# Four line equality

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a latex command for writing a symbol of equality with four parallel lines. I have tried to draw four lines in Detexify but it only returns the equivalence symbol of three parallel lines. 
Thank you!

Comment: Untested for LaTeX, but maybe `$\lower.5ex\hbox{$=$}\hskip-.8em\raise.5ex\hbox{$=$}$`?

Comment: Unicode lists such symbol as “strictly equivalent to”, U+2263. The only math font that provides it, as far as I can see, is STIX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a command, `\superequiv` that seems to be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\superequiv{\mathrel{\rlap{\raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$=$}}\raisebox{-0.5\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$ = $}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ A \superequiv B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing. Initially, I though of using `\mathrlap`,  which is defined by `mathtools`, but finally I have a solution that doesn't require it. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 12):

The symbol is classified in Unicode as U+2263 STRICTLY EQUIVALENT TO. The only math font providing it is, as far as I know, STIX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

\[{=\equiv\Equiv}\quad A \Equiv B_{\Equiv_{\Equiv}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With other math fonts you have to emulate it. Using the same idea as Bernard, here is a possibility with Computer Modern

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\Equiv{\mathrel{%
  \mathchoice
    {\Equiv@\textfont\displaystyle{.45}}
    {\Equiv@\textfont\textstyle{.45}}
    {\Equiv@\scriptfont\scriptstyle{.5}}
    {\Equiv@\scriptscriptfont\scriptscriptstyle{.55}}
}}
\newcommand{\Equiv@}[3]{%
  \rlap{\raisebox{#3\fontdimen5#12}{$\m@th#2 = $}}%
  \raisebox{-#3\fontdimen5#12}{$\m@th#2 = $}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[{=\equiv\Equiv}\quad A \Equiv B_{\Equiv_{\Equiv}} \]

\end{document}
```

I'm afraid that, with other fonts, you have to tailor the parameter (the third argument to `\Equiv@` in the code above).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is `\Equiv` in `unicode-math`, and all or nearly all OpenType math fonts include it.

In PDFTeX, the `\Equiv` symbol is in the `stix` and `stix2` packages.

Comment: This is already covered by egreg's answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke His answer was undoubtedly correct back in 2016. In 2020, there are two other options that it does not cover.

Answer (score -1):

- LaTeX: `\Equiv`
- Unicode: `=\below(=)`