# Remove spacing from equals so that it acts like a variable

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am trying to write a natural isomorphism (the adjunction) between two hom-functors. The spacing for the first argument `-` is removed, as desired, but the second argument `=` has the spacing of a binary operator, even though it only has a parenthesis on its right-hand side. I.e., the following:

```
i:\mathcal{D}(F-,=)\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(-,G=)
```

Looks like this:

[image: bad equals]

How can I remove the spacing after the `G` before the `=` so it's like the spacing after the `F` before the `-`?

Comment: `\smash{<argument>}` maybe? Something like `$\smash{=}$`

Comment: @azetina That works but is not its main purpose: `\smash` kills the vertical height of a symbol, but also results in a `\mathord` so the horizontal spacing is that of a symbol.

Comment: @AndrewSwann good observation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make something act as ordinary character in math mode it is sufficient to put it in curly brackets `{...}`.  This then becomes a `\mathord` and gets the appropriate spacing.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  i\colon\mathcal{D}(F-,=)\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(-,G{=})
\end{displaymath}

\newcommand{\eq}{{=}}
\begin{displaymath}
  i\colon\mathcal{D}(F-,\eq)\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(-,G\eq)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

You might want to define a short-hand, e.g. `\eq` for this as I have with the `\newcommand{\eq}{{=}}` above.

For this semantic case, @egreg suggest a better macro like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\blank}[1][1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or{-}\or{=}\or{\equiv}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\[
i\colon\mathcal{D}(F\blank,\blank[2])\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(\blank,G\blank[2])
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

@VF1 points to [Four line equality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333629/15925) to get a four line symbol.  However, that quickly gets unreadable, so I suggest using something like `<n>` above the dash.  Here are two macros `\nblank` and `\xblank` that will do that.  The second `\xblank` is a version that extends to fit the label above.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\blank}[1][1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or{-}\or{=}\or{\equiv}\or\nblank{#1}\fi
  }

\newcommand{\shortstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height 0.8ex}
\newcommand{\nblank}[1]{\overset{\langle #1\rangle}{\shortstrut\smash[t]{-}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xblank}[1]{\setbox\z@%
  \hbox{\m@th$\cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\relbar\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
    \displaystyle$}%
  \def\@tempa{\mkern1mu{\langle #1\rangle}\mkern1mu}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\m@th$\scriptstyle\@tempa$}%
  {\mathop{\shortstrut\hbox to \wd\tw@{\unhbox\z@}}\limits^{\@tempa}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  i\colon\mathcal{D}(F\blank,\blank[2])\Rightarrow
  \mathcal{C}(\blank,G\blank[2])
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
  r(\blank,\nblank{2},\dots,\nblank{n}) = (\nblank{n},\dots,\nblank{2},\blank)
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
  s(\blank,\dots,\xblank{1001637}) = \xblank{37}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the display math environment?

Comment: No, this works in any math environment and inline between dollars `$...$`.

Comment: This is definitely the most direct solution. I was hoping that perhaps the use of `-` for the first argument, `=` for the second, and `\equiv` for the third was just a hack (which results in the necessity of this workaround). Would you happen to know if there's something built-in for making an arbitrary number of horizontal bars as argument placeholders, perhaps from some category theory package?

Comment: Its just a weird way of showing the mwe. Why would he need to define a new command for it?

Comment: @azetina To distinguish the cases where `=` is not being used for the equality.  I regularly use `\newcommand{\Hodge}{{*}}` for the Hodge star operator, which does not have the usual spacing of the `*` symbol.

Comment: @VF1 rather than special case the arguments you can define a macro for the functor, so `\newcommand\foo[3]{\mathcal{#1}({#2},{#3})}`  would allow `\foo{C}{-}{G=}`

Comment: Regarding my comment, seems like this would be the way to go (still must be coupled with Andrew Swann's `\mathord` fix): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333641/126833

Comment: I suggest also using braces around `-`, so `F{-}`. I usually define `\blank` for a placeholder; apparently, the OP wants to denote differently the two placeholders, so probably `\blank` and `\blankdbl` or something like that.